# Database full backup,differential backup and log backup plan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, backup

I am working with DB backup, first I would like to get a roughly plan on weekly/daily backup. I have countered some problems when I am trying to get such a plan, What I tried is:

For weekly`FULL DATABASE BACKUP`, using: `BACKUP DATABASE name To Disk... WITH INIT,SKIP;`

1. Can I set it to `SKIP` and overwrite the old full backup file every week? If I did not add `EXPIREDATE` or `RETAINDAYS`, does that mean the current backup will not overwrite the existing one because the old one never expires?

   For daily `Differential DATABASE BACKUP`, using `BACKUP DATABASE name To Disk... WITH DIFFERENTIAL,INIT,SKIP;`
2. How does the SQL Server know which full backup is daily differential based on? By using `WITH FORMAT, MediaName='...'`? If so, does that mean for the first time I do the full database backup I need to format a new media set such as `DatabaseA` set for that database, and for the later back up, I could use `WITH NOFORMAT, medianame = DatabaseA'` to let sql server knows that differential backup should be attached to that full backup database?

   For transaction log backup, using `BACKUP LOG A TO DISK...`
3. I know it is not good to add `WITH INIT` to log backup, but how to handle the increasing size of log backup? `Shrinkfile(log)`each time I did the full database backup? Does that mean I could ignore the increasing size of transaction log before the next full backup comes?

Comment: Any suggested frequency for each type of backup? For example: Weekly Full backup; daily differential backup; daily log backup? shrinkle every week?

Comment: Most of the options you're asking about are only really relevant when backing up to tape, are you doing that, or to disk?

Comment: Just disk, not tape

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to try to save you a lot of time messing with outdated and mostly unnecessary backup options. Just use [Ola Hallengren's free scripts](http://ola.hallengren.com).

Next up, deciding backup frequency is a business decision as it relates to [RPO and RTO](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/12/letters-that-get-dbas-fired/). No one here can tell you how much data you're allowed to lose. One thing though: if you're thinking about taking log backups once a day, you shouldn't be in full recovery model.

That also relates to: [DON'T SHRINK YOUR DATABASE](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/). Your log file grows because you don't back it up either at all, or often enough. If you shrink it, it will grow again, and that's just not a smart way to administer a SQL Server. Either back it up more often, or switch to SIMPLE recovery.

That decision is between you and management, though.

Answer (score 0):

To add to all the other answers, as for the frequency of different backups, if the database is mission critical and so in FULL recovery model then a weekly FULL backup, daily DIFFERENTIAL backup and a LOG backup every 15 minutes will be the best possible solution. For less critical database, go for the weekly full and daily DIFFERENTIAL backup.

Comment: This isn't true at all, if they have RPO less than 15 minutes. Taking log backups every 15 minutes means they can lose 15 minutes of data.

Comment: Yes that makes sense...so log backups should be decided w.r.t the RPO. But we still can recover if we can grab a tail log backup. Moreover the guy asked for a backup plan, so I thought of giving one.